# xml element not indented properly

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

i have created a xml file using c# but the main problem is that it is not indented

i have used xmldocument.preserverwhitespace=true;

Comment: I remember hearing somewhere that the use of a condom can help against the spawning of unintended XML files.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using an XmlTextWriter, you can set the Formatting property :

```
XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter("c:\ouputfile.xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
xmlWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
```

Answer (score 0):

Strongly suggest you switch over to the new XML document model, based on XDocument. You can use LINQ to XML on it, and it's much easier to create, alter, and search XML than it ever wasin the old XMLDocument model. The new XDocument model can cut your code size by over half.

Comment: If you're going to downvote, please provide a reason, if for no other reason than to inform the original poster of the reason for disagreement. (Not to mention that silent downvoting is very rude.)